# React Hook Form with datepicker Range doesn't pick date

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker, react-hook-form

I got the following datepickers.
For the Start Date:

```
<Controller
    as={
        <DatePicker
            selected={travelRoute?.dateStart || new Date()}
            selectsStart
            startDate={travelRoute?.dateStart}
            endDate={travelRoute?.dateEnd}
            inline
        />
    }
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    valueName="selected"
    onChange={date => handleStartDateOnChange(date)}
    name="dateStart"
    placeholderText="Select date"
    defaultValue={null}
/>
```

For the End Date:

```
<Controller
   as={
    <DatePicker
        name="dateEnd"
        selected={travelRoute?.dateEnd || new Date()}
        onChange={date => handleEndDateOnChange(date)}
        selectsEnd
        startDate={travelRoute?.dateStart}
        endDate={travelRoute?.dateEnd}
        minDate={travelRoute?.dateStart}
        inline
    />
   }
   control={control}
   rules={{ required: true }}
   valueName="selected"
   onChange={date => handleEndDateOnChange(date)}
   name="dateEnd"
   placeholderText="Select date"
   defaultValue={null}
/>
```

Do  I need to add the datepicker props to the datepicker component or to the Controller Component?
The start Datepicker doesn't select the date and the end Datepicker doesn't change the startdate and isn't displaying the range.

I'm saving the data into the travelRoute state with setTravelRoute which is happening in the handleOnChange functions.

EDIT:
Added onChange handler:

```
const handleStartDateOnChange = date => {
    setTravelRoute(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        dateStart: date
    }))
};

const handleEndDateOnChange = date => {
    setTravelRoute(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        dateEnd: date
    }))
};
```

Comment: Show the onChange handlers

Comment: I added the onChange handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, you are using the wrong approach to customize your `onChange` event in `DatePicker`. And `onChange` event on `Controller` can't work neihter. Because in this case, you don't have to use `as=` syntax, but `render=` syntax like:

```
<Controller
    render={({ onChange }) => (
      <DatePicker
        ...
        onChange={date => handleStartDateOnChange(date)}
      />
    )}
    ...
  />
```

So your code becomes:

**Start Date**

```
<Controller
    render={({ onChange }) => (
      <DatePicker
        selected={travelRoute?.dateStart || new Date()}
        selectsStart
        startDate={travelRoute?.dateStart}
        endDate={travelRoute?.dateEnd}
        inline
        onChange={date => handleStartDateOnChange(date)}
      />
    )}
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    valueName="selected"
    name="dateStart"
    placeholderText="Select date"
    defaultValue={null}
  />
```

**End Date**

```
<Controller
    render={({ onChange }) => (
      <DatePicker
        name="dateEnd"
        selected={travelRoute?.dateEnd || new Date()}
        onChange={date => handleEndDateOnChange(date)}
        selectsEnd
        startDate={travelRoute?.dateStart}
        endDate={travelRoute?.dateEnd}
        minDate={travelRoute?.dateStart}
        inline
      />
    )}
    control={control}
    rules={{ required: true }}
    valueName="selected"
    name="dateEnd"
    placeholderText="Select date"
    defaultValue={null}
  />
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-brook-lzm1o?file=/src/App.js) a working example.

Note: I don't know why `DatePicker` in codesandbox looks so ugly. Could be the `Controller` because in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-datepicker-xzv0f) other codesandbox looks good.

Comment: Very very happy to ear that! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Any Idea why I only get an undefinied value out of those two datepickers?

Comment: Ciao, in my example I putted a button at the end of the page to verify if state is updated. If you select any date for start date, dateStart has a value. Then, if you select a date for end date that is before the minDate (in this case dateStart) dateEnd stills null. This could be your problem (even if I think you already verify that...). If I find other clues I will write another comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a different approach to the solution of this issue and wanted to share it.

I answered some related issue in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72585781/19320134

Anyway, one way to make the code more reusable is to put these controllers in separate files, so that only the function name is imported when calling them.

```
export const DateRange = ({ name, control, label }) => {
const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([null, null]);
const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;
 

return (
   <Controller
     //is a prop that we get back from the useForm Hook and pass into the input.
     control={control}
     //is how React Hook Form tracks the value of an input internally.
     name={name}
     //render is the most important prop; we pass a render function here.
     render={({
       //The function has three keys: field , fieldState, and formState.
       field, // The field object exports two things (among others): value and onChange
     }) => (
       <>
         <DatePicker
           selectsRange={true}
           startDate={startDate}
           endDate={endDate}
           onChange={(e) => {
             setDateRange(e);
             field.onChange(e);
           }}
           isClearable={true}
           className="form-control"
         />
       </>
     )}
     rules={{
       required: `The  ${label} field is required`,
     }}
   />
```

And you can call it in the necesary file like this

```
import { useForm, Controller, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import {DateRange} from "./your file !"

const defaultValues = {
  dateRange: [],
};

export default function ComponentUsingDateRange() {
const methods = useForm({
    defaultValues,
    mode: "onChange",
    });

    const { register, handleSubmit, control, setValue } = methods;

     return(
      <>
       <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <DateRange
         control={control}
         name="dateRange"
         label="Range of dates"
        />
       </FormProvider>
     </>
       
     );
}
```