# react date picker multi range with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-datepicker

The reason we use react hook form is that it decreases our state count and increases performance. But I didn't know how to do it when using Date range for one datepicker.
How to keep two data in one controller?

```
`() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null);
  const onChange = (dates) => {
    const [start, end] = dates;
    setStartDate(start);
    setEndDate(end);
  };
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={onChange}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      selectsRange
      inline
    />
  );
};`
```

If this piece of code is my code, I can only capture one value with selected, but I need to return 2 values. How can I use this in the best way with the react hook form?

```
 <Controller
            name="orderDate"
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <DatePicker
                selected={field.value}
                onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date)}
                selectsRange
              />
            )}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got the exact same issue last week, here is the solution...

You just need to pass (**at least**) the value to the "**Controller function**", you achieve that using only the field object.

In any case, When the **DatePicker component** is used for a date range, it will require a two-position vector data type, where the start and end dates are stored as a string. But if you try to manipulate and control this component via the **onChange function** that comes from the reack-hook-form it's gonna screw up the entire thing, because is made  for a one-to-one data flux. Then the processes are done separately but the vector is still sent to the controller. Here is the code!

```
              const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([null, null]);
              const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;
              <Controller
                //is a prop that we get back from the useForm Hook and pass into the input.
                control={control}
                //is how React Hook Form tracks the value of an input internally.
                name={name}
                //render is the most important prop; we pass a render function here.
                render={({
                  //The function has three keys: field , fieldState, and formState.
                  field, // The field object exports two things (among others): value and onChange
                }) => (
                  <>
                    <DatePicker
                      selectsRange={true}
                      startDate={startDate}
                      endDate={endDate}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setDateRange(e);
                        field.onChange(e);
                      }}
                      isClearable={true}
                      className="form-control"
                    />
                  </>
                )}
                rules={{
                  required: `The  ${label} field is required`,
                }}
              />
```

Comment: we have to define 2 states anyway, right? actually when asking this question, i meant to say can we save it from defining extra state?

Comment: In fact if you take a closer look you will notice that only one state is defined, which contains a vector with two positions, what happens is that these positions are subsequently named startDate and endDate. The DatePicker needs them to display and work correctly and the react-hook-form controller cannot handle this behavior. But the point is to capture the array through the control property. You achieve that using the field.onChange function to set the value for the field.